# Wrapping C++ function to take Lua table of strings using SWIG

Tags: c++, lua, swig, lua-table

I'm trying to wrap a C++ function that can receive Lua table of strings and use it as an array of strings in C++ function.

I could successfully do this using float type instead of string.

Here's my function.

```
static void readTable(float values[], int len) {

        for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
            printf("VALUE : %g", values[i]);
    }
```

And here's the typemaps part from SWIG interface (.i) file

```
// using typemaps
%include <typemaps.i>
%apply (float INPUT[], int) {(float values[], int len)};
```

It works fine when I call this function in Lua.

However, if I change the type to `std::string` instead of `float` and pass table of strings to the function, I get the following error in Lua.

```
Error in readTable expected 2..2 args, got 1
```

I don't know what this means and how to fix this.
Maybe I have to add something more to the SWIG interface (.i) file?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `typemaps.i` file only defines typemaps for [arrays of the primitive numeric types](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/7d11c2901e55829c760f420ed20cc9b62ee8f00c/Lib/lua/typemaps.i#L350-L359).

Thus I recommend that you write your own typemap.  Then you can also take an argument of type `std::vector<std::string>`, so you don't even need the length parameter.

```cpp
%module table_of_strings

%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void readTable(std::vector<std::string> values) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<values.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "VALUE : " << values[i] << '\n';
    }
}
%}

%include "exception.i"
%typemap(in) std::vector<std::string>
{
    if (!lua_istable(L,1)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: table expected");
    }

    lua_len(L,1);
    size_t len = lua_tointeger(L,-1);

    $1.reserve(len);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        lua_pushinteger(L,i+1);
        lua_gettable(L,1);
        $1.push_back(lua_tostring(L,-1));
    }
}

void readTable(std::vector<std::string> values);
```

```sh
swig -c++ -lua test.i
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/lua5.3 -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o table_of_strings.so -llua5.3
```

```lua
local tos = require"table_of_strings"
tos.readTable({"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"})
```

```
VALUE : ABC
VALUE : DEF
VALUE : GHI
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, I tried your code but it crashes as soon as I call `readTable` in Lua. I tried to figure out where it crashes by removing the code one by one, but it still crashed even when I emptied every code inside `%typemap(in) std::vector<std::string>{}` Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: @ZackLee Does it crash with the exact example from my answer?  What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry I didn't use your exact code. I figured out `%include <stl.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>` caused the crash `vector::capacity() EXC_BAC_ACCESS`. Now It works fine after I remove these includes.

Comment: No I found out it crashes when I add `typedef std::string string;
typedef std::vector vector;` in the SWIG interface. It works fine when I remove these. I don't understand why though.

Comment: Hey, could you please have a look at my question I just posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703758/proper-way-to-free-a-pointer-array-in-swig-input-typemap

Comment: Sir, Could you please have a look at my question I just posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848915/what-is-lua-len-alternative-in-lua-5-1